# Enabling Single Sign-On for Sites using Salesforce as the Identity Provider

Tags: force.com-sites, customer-portal, single-sign-on, identity

I was wondering if anyone has had success in trying to enabling single sign-on for sites using salesforce as the Identity Provider.

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sso_sites.htm

I have used the little chunk of code there and replaced the PingSpUrl with a few different values as I have tried to test this.

I had setup Salesforce as a Service Provider under the Identity Provider section.  I have also tried to using the Single Sign Settings and keep getting a cert error even though I did download from the Identity section.

In the doc above it mentions you need to pass org_id, portal_id and siteurl so I attempted to add those the the SAML Attributes in the provider but when you try to add organiztion_id is says "Reserved attribute key".  You also can't seem to add any value there it has to from the insert field list.

I am told it is doable and I suspect at this point if it is I am just overlooking something simple.

Any pointers to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We use SSO to Portal using Salesforce as the identity provider, and use a sites domain to isolate the sessions - I have written it up here: http://foobarforce.com/2012/12/07/salesforce-identity-provider-for-portal/ - you may be able to glean something useful from this

Comment: I opened this question with the specific intention of quoting your blog @Stephen I think you should post as an answer, because you'll get my vote

Answer (score 7):

We use Salesforce as an Identity Provider for SSO into our Customer Portal. We use a Sites domain to isolate the sessions - so that users' own org sessions are not clobbered by logging in to our portal.

I have written up what we did here: https://foobarforce.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/salesforce-identity-provider-for-portal/

There may be enough overlap with what you are wanting to do for this to be helpful.